# What is the reason the free world bloc doesn't supply armament to the National Unity Government of Myanmar (NUG)

Tags: western-world, weapons, myanmar

When it comes to Ukraine or Afghanistan, the so-called free world countries seem to help supply armament to those two; but when it comes to Myanmar, support seems to be lacking.

Is it because Myanmar has a fragmented ethnic group, fragile government, its geolocation is far away from the west or just simply Myanmar doesn't have enough natural resource to bargain?

Which is the biggest reason?

Is there any other reason to be considered?

Answer (score 2):

This verges on being too trivial, being answerable by a few [Wikipedia links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myanmar).

- Myanmar has been in a state of [civil war](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_conflict_in_Myanmar) for almost all of the time [since its independence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Myanmar#Independent_Burma).
- From 1962 to 2011 it was ruled by a succession of [military juntas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_Peace_and_Development_Council), which had one of the worst human rights records in the world:

> Forced labour, human trafficking and child labour are common. The Burmese military junta is also notorious for rampant use of sexual violence as an instrument of control, including allegations of systematic rapes and taking of sex slaves by the military ...

- In 2011, there was an attempt at [major reform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Myanmar#2011%E2%80%932016), which produced elections in 2015 and the installation of a democratic government in 2016. That produced some lifting of sanctions, but the [Rohingya genocide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rohingya_genocide) started the same year.
- In [late 2020](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Myanmar#2016%E2%80%932021), the "democratic" government, which had *carried out that genocide*, won a new election comprehensively. A new [military coup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Myanmar#2021%E2%80%93present) followed in early 2021.

The attempted [destruction or assimilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_rights_in_Myanmar#Freedom_of_religion,_minority_rights,_and_internal_conflict) of minority groups continued under the democratic government, which has destroyed its credibility. More than 70 years of civil war have wrecked the economy and made Myanmar one of the world's least developed countries.

They don't have money to buy arms, and nobody sees anything to gain by giving them any. It's a mess that no faintly responsible government wants to touch.